# spaCy model .from_disk doesn't load patterns

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

For a Named Entity Recognition task in Dutch with spaCy, I added entities using EntityRuler. When I add the ruler to the pipeline in my notebook:

```
nlp = spacy.load("nl_core_news_md")
ruler = nlp.add_pipe("entity_ruler", before="ner")
patterns  = complete_dicts # This is a list of dictionaries, e.g. [{"label": "PERSON", "pattern": "Staf Aerts"}, {"label": "PERSON", "pattern": "Meyrem Almaci"}]
ruler.add_patterns(patterns)
```

the NER-pipeline works very well. However, when I save it to my disk and then load this model again using

```
nlp.from_disk("path/to_model")
```

the model misses entities that are added through the EntityRuler.

I found nothing in the documentation why this would happen. I would be grateful for anyone who has an explanation for this! Thanks.

Comment: That should just work. How are you actually saving and loading the model? You should be using `spacy.from_disk`, for example. In the saved model directory there should be a `entity_ruler/patterns.jsonl` file that you can confirm has your patterns.

Comment: Hi! To save the model, I did `nlp.to_disk("path/to_model")`. For loading, `nlp.from_disk("path/to_model")`. The saving indeed creates a folder with all the steps, and within the `entity_ruler` there is the `patterns.jsonl` file. These are the right patterns, which is why I am confused this does not work!

Comment: Ah, I meant `to_disk` in my comment. Sorry for not catching the `from_disk` vs `load` bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To load a saved model, use `spacy.load`:

```py
nlp = spacy.load("/path/to/model")
```

More details about how `spacy.load` works (including `nlp.from_disk`): https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#pipelines